# R Shiny - ui.R seems to not recognize a dataframe read by server.R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a question about Shiny.  I'll preface by offering that I did spend time with Google and SO archives, tried a few things, but still somehow miss something.  I'll apologize for any posting faux pas and give thanks in advance for any guidance.

I'm trying what I believe is a very basic task in order to learn Shiny, adapting code from one of the Shiny gallery examples.  I read a csv file into a dataframe (`df.shiny`).  I want to select business performance data (ITBpct) related to one facility (levels of `df.shiny$Facility`) and display it in an SPC chart (using qcc).

My issue seems to be related to making the data from `server.R` available to `ui.R`.  I believe that the data is read into the dataframe (it prints in the console), but is not available to `ui.R`. I'm convinced that I've simply overlooked something, but haven't yet figured it out.

I'm using the folder structure noted on the Shiny site, with server.R and ui.R in a working directory subfolder ("Shiny-App-1") and the data in a subfolder to this folder (Shiny-App-1/data).

The code that I've inserted to help track the error runs through printing `SRV-2` and `UI-1` in the console.  Firefox opens.  Then the error.

```
options(browser = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe")
library(shiny)
runApp("Shiny-App-1")
```

**server.R Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(qcc)
print("SRV-1")  # for debugging

df.shiny = read.csv("data/ITBDATA.csv")
print(df.shiny) # for debugging
print("SRV-2")  # for debugging


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
    # assign xrow <- Facility

    print("SRV-3")  # for debugging
    selectedData <- reactive({  subset(df.shiny, Facility %in% input$xrow)  })
    print("SRV-4")  # for debugging

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({  qcc(selectedData$ITBpct, type = 'xbar.one')  })
})
```

**ui.R Code**

```
library(shiny)
print("UI-1")  # for debugging

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('SPC Chart by Facility'),
    sidebarPanel( selectInput('xrow', 'Facility', levels(df.shiny$Facility) ) ),
    mainPanel( plotOutput('plot1') )

))
```

**Error Message**

```
ERROR: object 'df.shiny' not found
```

I can make the data available. (Wasn't sure how to attach a sample to this note.)

**SESSION INFO**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plyr_1.8.1       forecast_5.4     timeDate_3010.98 zoo_1.7-11       doBy_4.5-10     
 [6] MASS_7.3-31      survival_2.37-7  gplots_2.13.0    car_2.0-20       ggplot2_0.9.3.1 
[11] lattice_0.20-29  qcc_2.3          shiny_0.9.1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is you are using `df.shiny$Facility` in your `ui.R` file and `df.shiny` is not defined there. The `ui` cannot see all the variables in the `server`, they have other ways to communicate.

To get this to work, you need to build the `selectInput` on the server, and then render it in the UI. In your server, add

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$facilityControl <- renderUI({
        facilities <- levels(df.shiny$Facility)
        selectInput('xrow', 'Facility', facilities )
    })

    selectedData <- reactive({  subset(df.shiny, Facility %in% input$xrow)  })
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({  qcc(selectedData$ITBpct, type = 'xbar.one')  })
})
```

and then change the ui to

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('SPC Chart by Facility'),
    sidebarPanel( uiOutput("facilityControl" ),
    mainPanel( plotOutput('plot1') )    
))
```

Comment: Hi ... many thanks!  This got me to the next step.  I'm now having other issues but I'll do a bit more reading and maybe another post.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you could put all your R objects that need to be accessible by both `server.R` and `ui.R` in a `global.R` file.

More on that: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html#global-objects