# obtain another UI element value in ui.R in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

It may be a very simple issue, but I can't seem to get it work.
In my `ui.R` I have a dropdown whose ID is "product", how do I use the selected value for product in another place in `ui.R` itself. 
I tried input.product, input.product.value etc...none worked
Any help?
To give more information: I have tried the following to get a hyperlink on my web page :

```
 server.R
    output$sppath <- renderText({
          link1<-paste("http://server2/projects/", input$product, "/collaboration/forms/collaborative%20documents.aspx?&SortField=Modified&SortDir=Desc",sep="")
   return(link1) })

  ui.R
     fluidRow(h6("Sharepoint:", a("Collaboration", href=textOutput("sppath")))),
```

With above code, the link under "collaboration" is created as

`http://shiny-server:8787/p/5620/%3Cdiv%20id=%22sppath%22%20class=%22shiny-text-output%22%3E%3C/div%3E`

What am I doing wrong? Why is the sppath not resolving properly? 
When I try just textOutput outside of `a` tag, it shows the full path.

Comment: I don't think you can. If your aim is to dynamically change a UI element, you should create a `uiOutput` in your `ui.R`. In `server.R` you define a `renderUI` that will depend on `input$product`. See `?renderUI` and `?uiOutput` for details.

Comment: I used conditionalPanel in ui.R in which I can have condition like "input.study.length>1" when study is a groupCheckbox element, I was hoping that there is something to extract the selected value also from the selectInput element

Comment: Is there a reason you keep using a `.` after input instead of a `$`, even after a previous comment and my answer noted otherwise?
And why the insistance in putting this all in ui.r? its exactly the same code as putting it in a renderUI, except that the latter actually works.
With reference to your newly posted code, it looks like theres an extra slash `input$product,"/","/`, and have you tried verbatimTextOutput?

Comment: I corrected the code above and removed the extra `/`, also tried `verbatiTextOutput` but no Luck. NOTE : Only reason why I was using `.` instead of `$` after `input` was because that is how you need to refer to an element in ui.R if you need to put any condition against it, I really don't mind if it is done in ui.R or server.R as long as there is a way to do it and I was just exploring the possibility of keeping everything in ui.R itself.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is input$product, not input.product, and what you want is
renderUI in your server.r which uses input$product, then call uiOutput in ui.r

Comment: I tried input$product in ui.R it doesn't work. I know it works in server.R when referring input elements and I know how to create rederUI elements, but I'm trying to do all in ui.R itself by referencing other ui elements

Comment: please edit your original post to show what you tried. Within the renderUI({}) in your server.r, you will be writing ui-like code. There is no way (nor is there ever intended to be a way) to reference input elements in the UI, thats what the server file is for.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered is pointing you on the right track. See this answer for syntax on `uiOutput` http://stackoverflow.com/a/23835738/4606130

Answer (score 0):

I'm able find the solution, here it is :

```
server.R
output$sppath <- renderUI({
      link1<-  paste("http://server2/projects/",input$product,"/collaboration/forms/collaborative%20documents.aspx?&SortField=Modified&SortDir=Desc",sep="")
 h6("Sharepoint:",tags$a( href=link1,"Collaboration"))
})

ui.R
   fluidRow(htmlOutput("sppath)),
```