# Error when running UI for shiny web app - object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I'm facing an issue while deploying my app on Rshiny cloud

I am getting the following error when I run the code below code for UI:

> Error in data$Type : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I've looked at many issues online but am unable to figure out what is wrong in my code

```
ui <- semantic.dashboard::dashboard_body(
      semantic.dashboard::dashboard_header(color = "blue",title = "Dashboard Demo",inverted = TRUE),
      semantic.dashboard::dashboard_sidebar(
         # size = "thin", color = "teal",
          semantic.dashboard::sidebar_menu(
            semantic.dashboard::menu_item(tabName = "Visualization", "Visualization", icon = icon("chart line")),
            semantic.dashboard::menu_item(tabName = "RawData", "RawData", icon = icon("table"))
        )
      ),
      semantic.dashboard::dashboard_body(
        shiny::fluidRow(
          column(width = 3, offset =0, div(style = "height:35px"),
                 selectInput("type",
                             "Type:",
                             c("All",
                               unique(as.character(data$Type))))
          ),
          column(width = 3, offset =0, div(style = "height:35px"),
                 selectInput("Bname",
                             "Business Name:",
                             c("All",
                               unique(as.character(data$Business_Name))))
          ),
          column(width = 3, offset =0, div(style = "height:35px"),
                 selectInput("BUnit",
                             "Business Unit:",
                             c("All",
                               unique(as.character(data$Business_Unit))))
          ),
          column(width = 3, offset =0, div(style = "height:35px"),
                 selectInput("region",
                             "Region:",
                             c("All",
                               unique(as.character(data$Region))))
          )
        ),
        semantic.dashboard::tab_items(
          selected = 1,
          semantic.dashboard::tabItem(
            tabName = "Visualization",
            # Create a new row for the table.
            plotOutput('waterfall')
          ),
          semantic.dashboard::tabItem(
            tabName = "RawData",
            # Create a new row f
              DT::dataTableOutput("table")
            ),
          shiny::downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Raw Data")
      )
    )
    )
```

Comment: Where is your data read in (e.g. is it in server, is it reactive, or is it in global/outside of UI and server) and what does it look like?

Comment: This answers your question: [Error in <my code> : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable)

Comment: And in particular, the problem is that you're subsetting `data`, which is a defined function (at least until you define it as something else). You should replace that name with something different (e.g., `dat`), or define it.

Comment: @megan - i have done the data manipulation in r and saved a csv in the same directory which i am reading in server in a dataframe - is it a correct way or should i make rds file and upload

Comment: What happens when you follow @asac and @phalteman's advice, to change your dataset name so it isn't `data`? If that isn't working and you aren't making changes to the dataset in the app itself, you might find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833631/r-shiny-ui-r-seems-to-not-recognize-a-dataframe-read-by-server-r

Comment: @Megan - thanks for pointing me to right direction , dataframe was not loaded because of which the error was coming in local now the error is gone in local but when i deploy this in server it gives same error which i understand is CSV load will not work directly so what should be the correct way to load the dataset will rds file work ?

Comment: The issue is that `data` is defined in `server` and not accessible directly by the ui. `data` is not defined  when `ui.R` is run. It only *appears* to work locally because you have manually defined `data` is in the environment. If you clean your environment and run the app locally, you will still see the same problem. If you used another name (such as `mydata`), you would see a clearer error `Object 'mydata' not found.`. To make a dynamic UI, you need to use a `uiOutput`/`renderUI` construct. Look up `dynamic UI shiny` with your favourite search engine to get more info. Good luck!

Comment: cool that is very well explained asac. appreciate that every single word went into my mind thanks alot